# How to pause the java program until the closure of the gnome terminal

Tags: java

I have this piece of program

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class ShellCommand {
    public void execShellCmd(String cmd) throws IOException{
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"gnome-terminal", "-x", "bash", "-c", cmd});
    }
}
```

cmd is a String that contains parameters such as:

`/home/fireworks/workspace/ABT/hello.sh`

where hello.sh is the sh file to run from java

The program works, only that, after opening the gnome-terminal continues normally not waiting for the closure of the gnome-terminal.

I already tried the method `waitFor();` but nothing changes

Is there any solution that allows the program to wait for the closure of the gnome-terminal?

Solved: Is gnome-terminal of ubuntu 15 the problem. I use xterm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class ShellCommand {
    public void execShellCmd(String cmd) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"gnome-terminal", "-x", "bash", "-c", cmd});
        System.out.println( "Started proc" );
        p.waitFor();
        System.out.println( "Done waiting" );
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        ShellCommand s = new ShellCommand();

        try {
            s.execShellCmd( "sleep 10; echo done" );
        } catch( Exception e ) {
        }
    }
}
```

I see the "started proc" printout, then it waits for the terminal to finish, then I see "Done waiting".

Comment: I made a copy and paste, but the program does not work as I want.

I see:

Started proc - 
The terminal that opens - 
Done waiting -
The terminal still working. - 
The terminal closes 
-- 
What I want to see: 
Started proc -
The terminal that works - 
The terminal that closes - 
Done waiting -

Comment: What version of java/linux are you using then?  I see exactly what you describe wanting on my (old) version on an old Fedora 14 box I have, and I see the same thing on a more recent Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: I have Ubuntu 15
I use Eclipse Mars
java version "1.7.0_80" (I build for android)

Comment: I did a test: it works with xterm.

The problem is the gnome terminal